Spotlight: kind:audio vs. kind:music
On the "Narrow your search results on Mac" web page, kind:audio and kind:music are mentioned separately. What does this actually mean? What is the practical difference between them?

Do you get different results and can you examine the metadata on the files returned by these two provided selectors?

I would guess that all music files are audio files but not all audio files are music files. For example, an audiobook might show up as an audio file but not as a music file. A voice memo might also show up as an audio file but not as a music file.

I don't know what you mean by audiobook, just a regular audio file or something different, but kind:music does affect voice memos.
